# How can I get my JAVA Method-Chaining to work?

Tags: java, method-chaining

I am trying to do some simple method chaining but always have the error "cannot find symbol" part way through.
e.g.:

```
public JButton[] getSignOnButtons() {
    return InitialFrame.getInitialPanel().getSignOnButtons();
}
```

I am implementing the MVC model, in the View Package I have 4 classes: View, InitialFrame, InitialPanel, NorthPanel.  For my Controller to communicate with the View package, I always go through the View Class.

My Controller Class needs to access attributes of View's classes, what's the best way?

I "cheated" it previously by making all the View classes' attributes public so I could just create a 'get' method from view 
e.g.

```
return InitialFrame.InitialPanel.Buttons;
```

Thanks for any help.

The error just says "cannot not find symbol" is each case.

**EDITED from this point down......

This is the whole View Package:

```
public class View {

    InitialFrame initialFrame;

    public View(){

        initialFrame = new InitialFrame();

    }

    public JFrame getInitialFrame() {
        return initialFrame;
    }

    public InitialPanel getInitialPanel() {
       return InitialFrame.getInitialPanel();
    }

    public JButton[] getSignOnButtons() {
        return initialFrame.getInitialPanel().getSignOnButtons();
    }
}
```

This is the InitialFrame Class:

```
public final class InitialFrame extends JFrame {

    private final InitialPanel initialPanel;

    public InitialFrame() {

        super("Welcome to the Sign-on Screen");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        initialPanel = new InitialPanel();        
        this.add(initialPanel);

        //this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
        this.setVisible(true);

        JButton[] test = initialPanel.getSignOnButtons();
        String newStr = initialPanel.getNorthPanel().getTest();    //Call to getTest
    }

    public InitialPanel getInitialPanel() {
        return initialPanel;
    }


}
```

//InitialPanel ___________

```
class InitialPanel extends JPanel{

    private BorderLayout InitialPanelLayout;
    private JButton[] signOnButtons;
    private NorthPanel northPanel;
    private JPanel southPanel;
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JLabel userNameLabel;
    private JTextField userNameTextField;

    public InitialPanel() {

        this.setSize(600, 600);
        InitialPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        this.setLayout(InitialPanelLayout);

        this.createPanels();
        this.formatCenterPanel();


        setVisible(true);
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Method is to create panels for all the Border Layout of initial Panel
     * @param none
     */
    private void createPanels() {

        //Graphics comp2D = new Graphics();
        //comp2D.drawString("Free the bound periodicals", 22, 100);

        northPanel = new NorthPanel();
        northPanel.setSize(600, 200);
        this.add(northPanel, "North");

        southPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(southPanel, "South");

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(leftPanel, BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);

        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(rightPanel, AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(centerPanel, "Center");

    }

    /**
     * Method is to format the center panel on the opening window.
     * It uses 4 row grid layout, top row is a container with Label and TextField.
     * @param none 
     */
    private void formatCenterPanel() {

        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        Container userName = new Container();
        userName.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        userNameLabel = new JLabel("UserName: ");
        userName.add(userNameLabel);
        userNameTextField = new JTextField(30);
        userName.add(userNameTextField);

        centerPanel.add(userName);

        signOnButtons = new JButton[3];
        signOnButtons[0] = new JButton("Sign-On");
        signOnButtons[1] = new JButton("Register");
        signOnButtons[2] = new JButton("Exit");

        for (JButton butt: signOnButtons) {
            centerPanel.add(butt);
        }    
        centerPanel.validate();
        centerPanel.repaint();
    }

    public JButton[] getSignOnButtons() {
        return signOnButtons;
    }

    public JTextField getUserNameTextField() {
        return userNameTextField;
    }

    public NorthPanel getNorthPanel() {
        return northPanel;
    }
}
```

ALL updated now...

Only one error remains: "non-static method getInitialPanel() cannot be referenced from a static context"

in View Class

```
public InitialPanel getInitialPanel() {
   return InitialFrame.getInitialPanel();
}
```

Final Edit:
The main solution was to use the 'this' keyword.
After that, I could use Controller to chain 3 or more methods to retrieve attributes buried in the View Package.

for example, in the View Class:

```
public JButton[] getSignOnButtons() {
    return this.initialFrame.getInitialPanel().getSignOnButtons();
}
```

**EDIT 12/25/2018
the this.keyword does not solve this every time.  It is still a tricky operation.
Sometimes I just allowed NetBeans to create the method itself because it says method not found even though it is named exactly the same.

Comment: Post the full error here as well as the class for your `InitialPanel` and `InitialFrame` if they are custom classes

Comment: added two classes in the View package

Comment: why is your variable name `InitialPanel` which is the name of the type?

Comment: changed names.
Posting all View Package: View, InitialFrame, InitalPanel, NorthPanel

Comment: @AdamMiller as mentioned in comments below, change this InitialFrame.getInitialPanel(); to this.initialFrame.getInitialPanel(); and you should be good to go. :-)

Comment: make your function signature `public static InitialPanel getInitialPanel()`  or call `getInitialPanel()` by instance of `InitialPanel`.

Comment: @Akash -  That is it! I tested it on two new methods that would have failed before using "this." . Thanks!!

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to solve. Like I said, I cheated it before and I spent so much time wondering why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @AdamMiller cool! Glad I am able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Method chaining works from left to right in way that value returned by left method must have right method implemented in the class;

for example;

`"  Hello  ".substring(1).trim()`

Notice that here `substring(1)` is returning `String` value, which has also `trim()` method implemented in its (`String`) class.

In your case;
`return InitialFrame.getInitialPanel().getSignOnButtons();`

you are returning `Initialframe` from `getInitialPlane()` method, but there is not implementation of `getSignOnButtons()` in `InitialFrame` class. That's why JVM is complaining.

Comment: public JButton[] getSignOnButtons()  is the method in InitialPanel

Comment: before updating code, it was returning `InitialFrame` class not `initialFrame` not object. That's why its getting error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `getSignOnButtons()` in `JPanel`. Perhaps it's in `InitialPanel`? if that is the case, the return type of `InitialFrame.getInitialPanel()` should be `InitialPanel` instead of `JPanel`.

Comment: BTW, if you used the Java convention and make the variable names start with a lowercase letter, it would be less confusing.

Comment: 1. i usually use lower -case, I will change it now.

Comment: 2. I use both return types InitialPanel and JPanel, both show error

Comment: is method `InitialPanel.getSignOnButtons()` public?

Comment: I posted InitialPanel. I think I always use public methods. Maybe I experimented with a couple here.

Comment: Alright then. Change the return type of `InitialFrame.getInitialPanel()` from `JPanel` to `InitialPanel` and it will work.

Comment: I get  "non-static method getInitialPanel() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Same thing goes for your variable `View.InitialFrame`: it should be declared as an `InitialFrame`, not a `JFrame`.

Comment: That should be corrected. All of the code is updated with one remaining problem.

Comment: Now that you've rename the variable, use is: `initialFrame` not `InitialFrame`: that's the name of a class.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to execute a method which is not present in JFrame class. When you are declaring this `JFrame InitialFrame;`, at compile time Java will check whether the method exists or not in JFrame class. Since it is not there in JFrame, you looks to be getting "cannot not find symbol" error.

Also, try to follow code standards - field names should be in lower camel case i.e. intialFrame.

Try below code (I have not compiled it though) -

```
public class View {

    private InitialFrame initialFrame;

    public View(){

        initialFrame = new InitialFrame();

    }

    public JFrame getInitialFrame() {
        return this.initialFrame;
    }

    public JPanel getInitialPanel() {
        return this.initialFrame.getInitialPanel();
    }

    public JButton[] getSignOnButtons() {
        return this.initialFrame.getInitialPanel().getSignOnButtons(); 
    }
}

public final class InitialFrame extends JFrame {

    private InitialPanel initialPanel;

    public InitialFrame() {

        super("Welcome to the Sign-on Screen");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        initialPanel = new InitialPanel();        
        this.add(initialPanel);

        //this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
        this.setVisible(true);

        JButton[] test = initialPanel.getSignOnButtons();
        String new = initialPanel.getNorthPanel().getTest(); 
    } 

    public JPanel getInitialPanel() {
        return this.initialPanel;
    }


}
```

I assume you have another InitialPanel class which is extending JPanel and having getSignOnButtons() method defined in it.

Comment: Thank you.

And, I always use lowercase, I messed one up, then I just went with it for once. lol.

Comment: @AdamMiller it happens some time. :-)

Comment: posted InitialPanel

Comment: InitalPanel class doesn't look proper as well. northPanel = new NorthPanel(); needs to be replaced with northPanel = new JPanel(); This looks more like a typo. :-)

Comment: Sorry! Just saw your NorthPanel class too.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error you are getting now?

Comment: the error is always "cannot find symbol".  Currently I am down to one problem: View.getInitialPanel()

Comment: NOW 
I get  "non-static method getInitialPanel() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Update your latest code after corrections in the question please.

Comment: All of the code is updated now. One problem left- see above.

Comment: As error says, this happens when try to call a non-static method using static context. Either make the getInitialPanel() as static method which I think won't serve any purpose or call the method using object instance and not the class name. From your code, this looks to be happening as you are using same name for object and class.

Comment: public InitialPanel getInitialPanel() {
   return InitialFrame.getInitialPanel();
} change this to public InitialPanel getInitialPanel() {
   return this.initialFrame.getInitialPanel();
} and your problem should be gone.